# DataAnnotations and Resx in class library

Tags: localization, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, embedded-resource, resx

For my application (ASP.NET MVC 3.0 RTM, Razor View Engine), I would like to use DataAnnotations for my models.  If I keep the model classes within the web project, I can have resx resources in App_GlobalResources or App_LocalResources without embedding the `.resx` into `.resources` files.

Ignoring newly spawned AppDomains and other considerations, this is ideal because changing something minor in a localized resource like a typo or incorrect translation doesn't require compilation.

However, after moving my models to a class library I don't see any way to keep `.resx` files as the output and still use DataAnnotations attributes.  Am I missing something?

The problem lies in the way the attributes find resources.  For instance, a "Name" property might look like this:

```
    [Display(Name = "MyEntity_Name", ResourceType = typeof(Validations))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="MyEntity_Name_Required", 
       ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validations))]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

This requirement for a strongly-typed resource wrapper has become the bane of my existence over the past 24 hours.

I've tried to genericize the wrapper, but it seems like the validation attributes specifically look for a property on the wrapper called `MyEntity_Name` for the DisplayAttribute and `MyEntity_Name_Required` for the RequiredAttribute.  I haven't dug any deeper into the DataAnnotations code to see if there is some magic I can pull off.  I was hoping someone else encountered this and had any ideas.

**The Question**
Is it possible to use DataAnnotations ValidationAttributes (including DisplayAttribute) in a class library without embedding the resx files into `.resources` files?

**The Gotchas :(**
In the future, I'd like to move from resx to database-driven resources with very minimal coding effort.  I can't do that right now because of limited resources (no pun intended).  So, I want to avoid bypassing the ResourceProvider.  Also, I want to avoid rewriting or wrapping all of the attributes in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace.

Comment: Looks like only compilation-time resources in WebForms views will pull from .resx with a build action of `Content`, otherwise they'll have to be marked `Embedded Resource` for DataAnnoations to use them anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes, you are missing View Models. Controller actions take/pass view models from/to views and not models. View models are classes which are specifically tailored to the needs of a given view. They contain the only the required properties and the proper formatting for the given view. A view model could be a subset of a model or an aggregation of multiple models (it depends on the requirements of the view). View models are always defined in the web project because they are very tightly coupled to views. So it is view models that you should localize/globalize with resources.

Example of workflow:

1. The controller action is invoked and it queries the repository to fetch a model
2. The controller maps the model to the corresponding view model ([AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could you here)
3. The controller passes the view model to the view and the view displays it with the proper formating/localization.

Conclusion: models should not be formatted/localized or they become more difficult to reuse.

Comment: In my team, I brought up the concern of moving ViewModels outside of the presentation layer, thereby abusing the MVC framework in general.  My concern was generally (yet, jovially) shrugged off because we wanted to keep validations centralized. What would be the correct way to manage the complexity of validations at the presentation layer and at the next layer? My take is that this is no different than Web Forms where we'd have UI validations and validate again at the next layer.

Comment: @Jim, it is difficult to keep validations centralized. Here's an example: suppose add/update views. In the `Add` view you don't have an `Id` property, you don't care about it because you are inserting. In the `Update` view the `Id` property is required because you are modifying an existing entity. You see how depending on the view your validation rules change? So personally I perform all simple validation (formatting, required, ...) on the view models and business validation on the models (username is already taken, ...).

Comment: thanks.  That's pretty much inline with my take on validations.  I'll have to discuss with others on my team, but it's good to know that I'm not crazy.